# MovieClipTexture 3D in Flare 3D (transparent bitmapdata clear issue)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, flare3d

I have an issue in the MoviClipTexture3D in flare3D. When I am working with non transparent bitmapdata everything works fin but if i use a transparent bitmapdata the sreenshot from previous frame still in place and nothing is cleared

i followed this example in the wiki :

http://wiki.flare3d.com/index.php/MovieClipTexture3D

any idea? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the super function call you should do this :

```
super( new BitmapData( width, height, transparent, 0x0 ), false);
```

it works prefect for me now